# Force index reset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below is how I prepare the DataFrame from a candle list obtained from an API

candle list contains the open, high, low, close, volume values as a nested

```
candles = [ [time.time() , random(1000 ,9999) , random(1000 ,9999) ,random(1000 ,9999),random(1000 ,9999),random(1000 ,9999) ] for i in range(10) ] 

def handler(candles):
    date_time, open_lst , high_lst , low_lst , close_lst , volume_lst = [],[],[],[],[],[]

    for item in candles:
        dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(item[0])/1000)
        date_time.append(dt)
        open_lst.append(float(item[1]))
        high_lst.append(float(item[2]))
        low_lst.append(float(item[3]))
        close_lst.append(float(item[4]))
        volume_lst.append(float(item[5]))

    ## creating the data frame 
    coin_data_frame = {
        'dt': date_time,
        'open': open_lst,
        'high': high_lst,
        'low': close_lst,
        'close': close_lst,
        'volume': volume_lst }

    df = pd.DataFrame(coin_data_frame , columns= ['dt','open','high','low', 'close', 'volume'] )

    

    rolling_mean = df['close'].rolling(window=5, min_periods=5 ).mean()
    rolling_mean2 = df['close'].rolling(window=10, min_periods=10 ).mean()
    df['5_sma'] = rolling_mean
    df['10_sma'] = rolling_mean2
    df.dropna(subset = ["5_sma"], inplace=True)
    df.dropna(subset = ["10_sma"], inplace=True)



    puts(colored.yellow(str(df)))
    
    return df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

The line `puts(colored.yellow(str(df))` show the dataframe but the index does not start from 0 instead it starts form 9 for some reason, I tried to use `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`  but it does not seem to fix my problem I can still see that the dataframe starts with 9

Comment: I get "NameError: name 'candles' is not defined" when I try to run your code.  Simplify it and make it runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
return df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

or

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
return df
```

You have used `return df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`  which is wrong because when `inplace=True` the method returns None. Check [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) here.

#### Fixed code:

```
def handler(candles):
    date_time, open_lst , high_lst , low_lst = [],[],[],[]
    close_lst , volume_lst = [],[]

    for item in candles:
        dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(item[0])/1000)
        date_time.append(dt)
        open_lst.append(float(item[1]))
        high_lst.append(float(item[2]))
        low_lst.append(float(item[3]))
        close_lst.append(float(item[4]))
        volume_lst.append(float(item[5]))

    ## creating the data frame 
    coin_data_frame = {
        'dt': date_time,
        'open': open_lst,
        'high': high_lst,
        'low': close_lst,
        'close': close_lst,
        'volume': volume_lst }

    df = pd.DataFrame(coin_data_frame , 
                      columns=['dt','open','high','low', 'close', 'volume'] )

    rolling_mean = df['close'].rolling(window=5, min_periods=5 ).mean()
    rolling_mean2 = df['close'].rolling(window=10, min_periods=10 ).mean()
    df['5_sma'] = rolling_mean
    df['10_sma'] = rolling_mean2
    df.dropna(subset = ["5_sma"], inplace=True)
    df.dropna(subset = ["10_sma"], inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return df

candles = [ [time.time() , np.random.randint(1000 ,9999) , 
             np.random.randint(1000 ,9999) ,
             np.random.randint(1000 ,9999),
             np.random.randint(1000 ,9999),
             np.random.randint(1000 ,9999) ] for i in range(10) ] 

print (handler(candles))
```

Output:

```
dt    open    high  ...  volume   5_sma  10_sma
0 1970-01-19 18:27:20.858940  2370.0  1095.0  ...  4547.0  5433.6  4643.6

[1 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: I tried `reset_index(drop=True)` and i still get the same output starting with 9